# KnockOut Data-Bind Visible Causes Bad HTML

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I use bootstrap with KnockOut.
When I use classical way, it looks like below.

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="element2" class="field-title">Kazandıran Şube</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" tabindex="15" data-bind="options: BranchList, optionsText: 'Label', optionsValue: 'StringValue', value: CustomerDataTransformObject.Customer.ConsolidationPlace, newChosen: {}"></select>
</div>
```

[image]

But when I use visible binding, it crashes like this.

```
 <div class="col-md-6" data-bind="visible: CustomerDataTransformObject.Customer.Type() == 'Tüzel/Kurumsal'">
    <label for="element2" class="field-title">Tüzel/Kurumsal Tip</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" tabindex="10" data-bind="options: CommercialTypeList, optionsText: 'Label', optionsValue: 'StringValue', value: CustomerDataTransformObject.Customer.Commercial.Type, newChosen: {}"></select>
</div>
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle of this? Is the issue that the dropdown is on the same line as the label just? And this only occurs with the visible binding? ie if you remove visible binding does it look as expected?

Comment: I too would like to see a fiddle. I cannot read this language and there are too few context clues to actually see the problem.

Comment: The `visible` binding controls whether the item is `display: none`, which means that it will not occupy your 6-column space when hidden. Is that the issue?

Comment: Where is the `element2` here?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is totally about data-bind: visible. Because when you use visible binding for div, it can't calculate the real size of it. So I had to fix the size of select component. The unique solution is adding  `$(element).css("width", "100%");` to **newChosen** binding definition.